# Getting data from DB into array with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have a database table with events in them:

```
id |    title    | description | day_start  | day_end    | user_id

1  |   sometitle | blabla      | 2011-04-20 | 2011-04-21 |   1
2  |   title 2   | bleble      | 2011-04-20 | 2011-04-21 |   1
```

I want to read this out form my db with a foreach loop.

I want to store this into `$data[day_start]`

For example: `$data['2011-04-21']` should contain two arrays in this case, one for each event. I'm not sure how to do this. I had the following code (in CI):

(the `$start` argument is a date, like 2011-04-20).

```
    public function get_event_data($start)
{   
    $data = array();

    $query = $this->db->query(
                                "SELECT * 
                                 FROM tblEvents
                                 WHERE user_id = '" . $this->session->userdata('id') . "'
                                 AND day_start = '" . $start . "';"
                             );

    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[$row->day_start]  = array(
                            'title'         =>          $row->title,
                            'description'   =>          $row->description,
                            'day_start'     =>          $row->day_start,
                            'day_end'       =>          $row->day_end,
                            'time_start'    =>          $row->time_start,
                            'time_end'      =>          $row->time_end,
                            'user_id'       =>          $row->user_id
                  );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

However, as expected, this only outputs the SECOND event (since I'm using '=', which overrides the data that gets put in the array the first time):

> Array ( [2011-04-20] => Array (
>   [title] => Test Event 2 [description]
>   => second event. [day_start] => 2011-04-20 [day_end] =>
>   2011-04-20 [time_start] => 12
>   [time_end] => 13 [user_id] => 1 ) )

(the data here differs from the one i provided at the top, but it's about the idea, not the data).

I tried using .= but then php complains that there's no such index to be found.. Cause I didn't initiate it and I'm trying to add to it.

So then, I tried with a `if(isset($data[$start])` block, but that didn't really get me anywhere either.

I want to grab all the events for a particular day and put them in an array so I can process it further in my application.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$data[$row->day_start][]  = array(
```

The second set of `[]` will create an auto-iterative array, so no data will be over written.

Comment: Cool, the auto-iterative array is an immensely useful concept!!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand, CI allows you to return an array of results, which is doing the exact same thing as your code above.

`return $query->result_array();`

Would do it.

If you don't want **all** your data in the array, then don't select `*` and only take what you require.